Exporting Test results from Test Explorer Window in Visual Studio 2022
Is there a way to export the test results that appear in the Test Explorer Window?  I know a test results file is created for each test run, but the test explorer window gives me a full picture (for example if I have had to re-run a single test).  And so keen to export the full test explorer window as a single file.


In your solution folder, add a file named test.runsettings which can config your test.

Add below code in the file:
 <RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
   <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory> 
   <TargetFrameworkVersion>net8.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>   <!-- your .NET Version -->
    <MaxCpuCount>4</MaxCpuCount>
   <TestSessionTimeout>60000</TestSessionTimeout>
  </RunConfiguration>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Blame" enabled="True">
        <Configuration>
          <CollectDump/>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
  <LoggerRunSettings>
    <Loggers>
      <Logger friendlyName="trx" />  <!-- if you dont have any other logger -->
    </Loggers>
  </LoggerRunSettings>
 </RunSettings>


In the visual studio -> Test ->Configure Run Settings-> Select Solution Wide runsettings File.
Select the test.runsettings.


Run the test, in the .\TestResults folder there will be the Test Result File.


